# rtf format to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, rtf

Is there any way to convert rtf format to pdf using PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with pure PHP, you can probably use HTML as an intermediary:

1. Convert RTF to HTML
   http://freshmeat.net/projects/rtf2htm/ , http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1930-PHP-RTF-to-HTML-converter-with-latin-character-support.html
2. Optionally: clean up the HTML
   http://htmlpurifier.org/
3. Convert HTML to PDF
   http://dompdf.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenOffice command line interface for that. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90363/getting-php-to-read-doc-files-on-linux/93504#93504) to a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

[Ted](http://www.nllgg.nl/Ted) is the tool you're looking for. Ted brings also a script called rtf2pdf.sh you can execute by PHP to create a PDF file.

Comment: I couldn't install Ted gracefully on latest Debian GNU/Linux (Stretch 9.9). An attempt resulted in breaking up library dependencies. Looks like Ted is dependent on some very ancient libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out livedocx livedocx.com .  The latest Zend Framework 1.10 has a ready built module to help you out.  You can read more about it at this place http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/template-based-document-generation-using-livedocx-and-zend-framework