# How to change already existed RTF files to PDF files by using php script..?

Tags: php, drupal-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rtf format to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019017/rtf-format-to-pdf)

This is very important for me.. We have to change many existing rtf files into pdf files in our live website.. So plz kindly give a solution... I need a php script to change many existing rtf files to pdf ...!!

Thank u in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not supposed to be used to convert files. It's a scripting language for web sites.

What you need is a) a software which can convert from RTF to PDF and can be called through command line and b) a batch script which calls the software.

An example of such software is [GhostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript).

Since you didn't specify any information in you question, further help is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with open office:
Download http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter DocumentConverter.py and palce it in the same folder with soffice.exe. Then start OOffice as a service ( soffice "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" -headless -norestore -nologo -nofirststartwizard )  and then in PHP use it like this:

```
exec('python "path\to\this\file\DocumentConverter.py" path_to_doc\test.rtf path_to_output_pdf\test.pdf"');
```

Comment: Sorry .. I tried but im not getting through this way..