# How to insert php variables to word doc template and also convert to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word

I am still new to programmer but i am doing just good.

This is what i attempt to achieve, get a template in word doc with some texts and blank spaces, then populate those spaces with variables coming from a form field processed in php.
e.g

```
**in Microsoft word file i have:** 
 Name: 
 Age:
 Sex:

**Then in my php file**
I have 
$name;
$age;
$sex;
```

so i want to populate the word doc with the variables from the processed form and also be able to download the form already populated in same .doc and also PDF format

Comment: Does the user work from within Microsoft Word (fetching data from a database) or work in a web frontend, downloading a Word document and opening it maybe in OpenOffice?

Comment: @GuidoLeenders NO, the user works from the web, its a cv builder, after the user enters he/her details, the detailes will be used to create the CV/resume wg=hich already is in a template just to fill in the detailes the user types in the form fields

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the document needs to be downloaded from a web application and probably needs no extensive customising by the user. In that case, I would recommend using docx format instead of doc, or RTF.

In RTF you will have problems making tables look good, dito headings/footers, but it is further rather easy and portable to generate. If you choose docx, you can generate the document as XML and compress. There are various libraries for this purpose.

Since you indicate you will also need a PDF representation, I would recommend choosing a library that generates to DOCX as well as RTF and PDF. For Java, my advice would be JasperReports. For PHP, being not an enterprise platform (end of flame war), you might consider alternatives such as http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/12/18/7923.aspx or LiveDOCX.

If you choose to generate the two output types through different means (introducing more maintenance and possible future bugs), I would recommend generating RTF and publishing the RTF as PDF, for instance as described in [rtf format to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019017/rtf-format-to-pdf)