# how do I exclude MS Word created junky chars in regEx with php

Tags: php, regex, ms-word

I read the MS Word document with $text = fread($filename, $filesize);

then when I echo the $text it has some chars that browser cannot display properly and outputs some broken chars. I'm trying to clear them out with following regex:

`preg_replace('/[^\w]/','',$text);` but it's not working as I want.

Can anybody help, please?

Comment: That's not the right approach. Use a conversion tool (e.g. antiword or libroffice headless).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting PHP to read .doc files on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90363/getting-php-to-read-doc-files-on-linux)

Comment: you are right about tools, but i'm using shared hosting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you should use a tool that transforms the .doc-file into something more usable like plain/text.

Otherwise you could try the following regexp when outputting each line, which only keeps digit-, word- and whitespace-charaters in the string:

```
preg_replace("/^([^\d\w\s])$/i", "", $text);
```